Python3 Type Safe partial_apply
I'm trying to implement a helper function which partial apply arguments to a specific function and return a new function
from typing import Any, Callable, TypeVar
from typing_extensions import ParamSpec

P = ParamSpec('P')
R = TypeVar('R')

def partial_apply(fn: Callable[P, R], *args: subset_of[P.args], **kwargs: subset_of[P.kwargs]) -> Callable[remainder_of[P], R]:
    def wrapper() -> R:
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

def add(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    return a + b

add_1 = partial_apply(add, 1)
add_1(2) # 3

But subset_of and remainder_of is obviously not supported here, so is there any solution?

If your function expects specific arguments and partially applies some of them, the remaining arguments could be explicitly stated in the typing. If your function expects generic arguments and keyword arguments, how does it decide what arguments to apply? (from your example, how is what you want partial_apply to do different from https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial?)

Related/potential duplicates: How to make precise function annotation after Partial applied, How does pyright retain argument type information with `partial`?.

@Grismar It's exactly the same thing as functools.partial, but I'm wondering what is the mechanism behand  functools.partial, and If I need to do this, I mean, exclude a parameter from P.args, how to achieve that?

Have you read the answers at the second link shared by @insync? It appears the authors of the two questions linked there were wondering the same.

functools.partial is special-cased by type checkers. mypy implements it via a plugin (here), pyright has the logic hardcoded somewhere as well. You can't accurately mimic that behaviour with available typing forms.
